# Embedding nested form type fields in empty symfony form

Tags: php, forms, doctrine, symfony4

I have form type for a `Shop` entity. This links in a 1-1 relationship to a `ShopAddress` entity.

When I nest the `ShopAddress` entity it [appears blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uftb0.png) when creating a new shop. How can I get this to render with the relevant blank fields when creating a new `Shop`?

```
// App/Froms/ShopType.php
class ShopType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add( "name" ) // rendering fine
            ->add( "shopAddress", CollectionType::class, [
                "entry_type" => ShopAddressType::class, // no visible fields
            ] )
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            "data_class" => Shop::class,
        ));
    }
}

// App/Froms/ShopAddressType.php
class ShopAddressType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("addressLine1", TextType::class ) // not rendering
            ->add("addressLine2") // not rendering
            ->add("postcode") // not rendering
            ->add("county"); // not rendering
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            "data_class" => ShopAddress::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this is somewhat getting me close https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#by-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Solved it. [Docs had the answer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#by-reference) You need to add it as a new `FormBuilderInterface` object in the `add()` method:

```
class ShopType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("name", TextType::class)
            ->add(
                // nested form here
                $builder->create(
                    'shopAddress', 
                    ShopAddressType::class, 
                    array('by_reference' => true ) // adds ORM capabilities
                )
            )
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            "data_class" => Shop::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Adding `array('by_reference' => true )` will allow you to use the full ORM (Doctrine in my case) capabilities (e.g. `$shop->getAddress()->setAddressLine1('this string to add')`).